# Why does variable stop increasing too early in Matlab loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, concatenation

I have the following code and error. Question follows below:

```
clear all, close all

%Reading data in from excel
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('test.xlsx');

%Looking through the raw excel data to find all instances of 'Instruction: '
instructionindex = find(strcmp(raw,'Instruction: '));

%Making an array using a loop that takes the content of each cell in column 2, indexed by instructionindex
instruction = []
    for i = 1:numel(instructionindex)
        instruction = [instruction; raw{instructionindex(i),2}];
    end
```

> Error using vertcat
>   Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
>   Error in test2 (line 27)
>           instruction = [instruction; raw{instructionindex(i),2}];

and in the workspace I can see that while instructionindex is 24 x1 double, i only increases inside the loop to 7. That leads to a value (!) "instruction" of 6 x 5 char. I am not sure if this is somehow related to the fact that the content I am trying to bring together in the array "instruction" are strings.

**My question: How can I get all the indexed 24 contents out in array "instruction" and what causes i to stop at 7?**

EDIT: To further clarify why I think this is related to cells in column 2 containing strings: If I use 
    instruction = [instruction; raw{instructionindex(i),4}];
 where column 4 contains numbers, everything works fine! I get  two vectors of a size 24 each and concatenation works as well.

Comment: If the strings are not the same length you cannot concatenate them into a character array (unless you whitespace pad everything). This is the same as trying to vertically concatenate a `1x3` vector with a `1x2` vector. It doesn't make mathematic sense.

Comment: Thanks @ excaza, that makes sense? But why does the  variable stop increasing, causing the different sized vector? The content of column 2 are strings, if I use a different column that has numbers this does not happen and I get two arrays both sized 24.

Comment: Sorry @excaza, I misread your comment. Your were referring to the STRINGS. I will try to find a way around that! Will reprt back asap. Might as well post it as an answer since I very much think this might have been it :)

Comment: `i` stops increasing because MATLAB ceases execution on error. MATLAB represents strings as arrays of characters and arrays of different shapes cannot be concatenated. While numeric arrays also have the same limitation, each number is not an array of numbers.

Comment: HI @excaza, I have been trying to just convert the content of the cells to chars and then to numbers, but I keep failing. I figured that would help me work around the problem since the strings are of two types only (4 and 5 characters long, respectively). I could work with those two numbers to tell apart which was which. I tried str2num(raw{instructionclose(i),2})

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if we didn't have to guess what your data looks like. See: how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Fair enough! I guess your explanation for the error is correct so you can post it as an answer and I can accept it. As for the actual solution, I assume it's related to finding a way to convert the strings and I realized that is another question altogether (and I will post that separately).